# Lambda / Pre-signed url access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I wrote a lambda function who return a pre-signed url for documents in S3 Buckets.

The code is really simple :

```
            const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: myFile.Key,
                Expires: 20
            })

            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "url": url
                }),
            };
```

The funny thing is when I call this function locally (with serverless framework) like this :

```
sls invoke local -f getEconomyFile -d '{ "queryStringParameters": { "key": "myfile.pdf" } }'
```

It's working ! I have a url which give me the file.

But when I deploy to AWS Lambda, the function return a URL which always says "access denied" on the file :

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>93778EA364B3506B</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        yqnPC0SeIVE3/Pl7/d+xHDJ78=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Why is it working locally and not deployed ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your signed URL expires 20s after it is generated. Any chance that it simply expired? The default is 15m.

Comment: Nop, I tried to remove the Expires parameter and it's not that :-/

Comment: Does the IAM role in use by the Lambda function actually allow S3 GetObject to the bucket in question? The pre-signed URL generation does not itself do any validation of the credentials afaik. If that's not it, then I'd check that the pre-signed URL hasn't somehow been corrupted and that your client is time-synced.

Comment: Not seems to be that, in my serverless file configuration : iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: s3:*
        Resource: arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME.

Comment: You also need object permissions via arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*

Comment: Oh you are right !! Now I have still access denied but even from local invoke and if I put the bucket visible to the public everything works fine !! So this is a problem about my bucket configuration ! Thank you very much @jarmod

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that you are using temporary credentials to sign that url (provided to you via the Lambdas Role). If those credentials expire, which can happen before the url expires, the url will no longer work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a list of things to check when pre-signed URLs do not work:

1. Check that the IAM policy of the signing credentials (the Lambda function IAM role in this case) permits access to download the S3 object in question (via `s3:GetObject` permission on the relevant object ARN such as `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*`).
2. Make sure that your IAM policy actually includes the appropriate object-level ARN such as `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*` or `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/images/*`. It is a common mistake to indicate a bucket-level ARN such as `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME` but that will not work.
3. Check that the URL hasn't expired.
4. Check that the credentials used to sign the URL haven't expired. This is a common problem when using temporary STS credentials to pre-sign URLs where the credentials expire before the pre-signed URL expires.
5. Check that the client is time-synced.
6. Check that the URL hasn't been mangled in transit or encoded in some way.

### Note on IAM credentials

Even if your IAM credentials do not permit access to the S3 object(s), it is possible to use those credentials to create a pre-signed URL (a purely local computation**) but that URL will not actually allow you to access  the object because the credentials underpinning the pre-signed URL do not have access to the object.

** you can tell this is a local computation and does not involve any calls into AWS by pre-signing an object such as `s3://notmybucket/cat.png`. That will work and generate a pre-signed URL, but it will not actually be usable to retrieve that object.

Comment: Future Googlers: Notice that asterisk! I spent quite a while debugging what I thought was an issue on the client upload side... turned out, the IAM user had "all S3 actions" for `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME`, which looked right. Why not? Changing it to `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME*` resolved the issue.

Comment: @anonymouscoward I'm guessing that you meant to write arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/* (with trailing slash asterisk) rather than arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME* (with just trailing asterisk).

Comment: The /* after the ARN is super important - thanks for your in-depth list!

Comment: @RonHolmes agree that this seems to be a common error, so I've called it out in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-full-control-acl/

As access to a bucket is given to other accounts, if they put an object in the bucket, the account owner doesn't get automatic access to those put files.  To fix this you need to add this to your commands:

```
--acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Such as

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket accountB-bucket --key example.txt --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

or

```
aws s3 cp s3://accountA-bucket/test.txt s3://accountB-bucket/test2.txt --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Otherwise you leave the ACL for the object hyper specific to the other account and user that pushed the file.

Hope that helps.